# Get timestamp/timecode information from c# Flashplayer

Tags: c#, flash, youtube, timestamp

I am embedding a Flashplayer window in my c# program to view youtube/vimeo videos. I am using the AxShockwaveFlashObjects module.

Is there a way to get the timestamp/timecode information from the flashplayer window?

Essentially I'm trying to make a Mark In, Mark Out feature where someone can click a button and a textbox will populate with the current timecode of the video playing.

Thanks

Comment: You can communicate between C# and FlashPlayer via the FlashPlayer `ExternalInterface` class.   This will involve adding code the swf file though.

Comment: Do you mean the file has to be downloaded and opened locally?  I am just feeding the flash window a youtube URL to have it play;

Comment: No, what I'm saying is the swf file has to expose the functionality it wants to share.  So whomever made that swf (or you if you have the source files) need to add some code to it to be able to pass data back and forth between the host (your C# program) and the SWF.

Comment: I'm not really looking for timestamp info that is embedded in the flash video.  I more so looking for the current position of the playhead of the flash window as a whole.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. There is no magic way to get it though without the flash app deliberately exposing that functionality.